Bypass Fiddler configuration not working for non-browser
I need exclude an URL from the Fiddler settings, which should be routed internally and not via proxy. Fiddler is configured to act as system proxy and is monitoring all connections.
For this I'm using Tools -> Options -> Connections -> "Bypass Fiddler Classic for URL's that start with:".
The config looks like this: <-loopback>;internal.com
This works when I enter the URL in Edge or Chrome. The traffic is not showing up as expected.
But when I do a request form my .NET 8 application (default proxy points to Fiddler 127.0.0.1:8888 through HTTPS_PROXY environment variable), I see the traffic in Fiddler but Fiddler is not filtering out the URL.
In the Fiddler documentation https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledge-base/optionsui there is a paragraph that describes the bypass list, but it seems to be a bit outdated:

The IE should bypass Fiddler list controls which requests should not
be sent through Fiddler Classic at all when it is registered as the
system proxy. Note that this list is generally only respected by
WinINET clients like Internet Explorer.

As far as I know, Chromium based browsers do not rely on WinINET anymore thus they probably have re-written the feature to make it work for Edge and Chrome (just an assumption).
My workaround is to set the bypass list on WebProxy in the application code for local development but I would prefer to avoid that.
Does anyone have a deeper understanding of that feature and why the filtering is not working when the request is made by another process?

could you try using the code `WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888");
proxy.BypassList = new string[] { "internal.com" };
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
Proxy = proxy,
UseProxy = true
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);` to bypass url

What do you want - make Fiddler not intercept the HTTPS connection from your app or intercept the https traffic but hide the traffic in Fiddler?

@JalpaPanchal This is my workaround. Also using NO_PROXY environment variable would work. So this workaround is good enough for me.
At Robert: I wanted fiddler to NOT intercept traffic for specific urls from all processes and not just browsers.

The problem you are facing because the way Fiddler handles the bypass list might not affect .NET applications as expected, especially when using the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable. When you set the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable in your .NET application, it forces all traffic through the specified proxy. However, the bypass list in Fiddler options is primarily respected by WinINET clients. Many modern applications, including .NET applications, might not honor this list the same way as browsers like Edge or Chrome do.

To resolve this issue is you could use  NO_PROXY Environment Variable or set bypass list in the .net app
